# Tricky multivariable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate the limit without using L'Hopital's rule:
$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} ~\log|y|$

Comment: Try using polar coordinates after you have convinced yourself that the limit exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit does not exist.
I show two paths that give different limits:

---

**Path 1.** Consider $(x(t), y(t)) = (0, t)$ for $0 < t < 1$.
The function in consideration simplifies to $|t|\ln t$ and it is standard to see that this limit is $0$. (Can be done without L'H.)

---

**Path 2.** Consider $(x(t), y(t)) = \left(\dfrac{1}{\ln t}, t\right)$ for $0 < t < 0.5$.

The function in consideration simplifies to
$$-\sqrt{1 + t^2(\ln t)^2}.$$
The limit of this is $-1 \neq 0$.

Comment: (+1) … concise and clear

Comment: the simplified version should be $-\sqrt{1 + t^2 (\ln t)^2}$, because for $t \in (0,0.5)$, we have $\ln t < 0$ (forgetting to take this into account led to my incorrect answer earlier lol)

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Indeed! Thanks for pointing it out. Have fixed it.

Comment: Ah...I see thanks for pointing that mistake @AryamanMaithani